# How can I join a table on itself to get the first or the last for each unique item?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following MySQL query that I have been working on for some time. I am trying to get a single unique record for each `list_id` in the `in` statement. I am joining the table on itself and checking the `lists.ordered` table to determine if I need to grab the first or the last order item.

```
SELECT lists.ordered, 
       cnt1.* 
FROM   cnt_lists AS cnt1 
       LEFT JOIN lists 
              ON cnt1.list_id = lists.id 
       LEFT JOIN cnt_lists AS cnt2 
              ON ( cnt1.list_id = cnt2.list_id 
                   AND ( ( lists.ordered = 1 
                           AND cnt1.id < cnt2.id ) 
                          OR ( lists.ordered = 0 
                               AND cnt1.id > cnt2.id ) ) ) 
WHERE  cnt2.id IS NULL 
       AND cnt1.list_id IN ( '3176', '3295', '3296' ) 
       AND cnt1.listable_type = 'App\\Models\\Movie';
```

It is working great to grab the last item, but when I try to grab the first order item it actually grabs the second.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Sample Data:

```
id     list_id   listable_id   listable_type      order   created_at            updated_at
2226   3296      7             App\Models\Movie   1       2016-12-02 12:56:29   2016-12-02 15:07:42
2224   3296      1             App\Models\Movie   2       2016-11-29 00:06:57   2016-12-02 15:07:42
2227   3296      9             App\Models\Movie   3       2016-12-02 12:56:35   2016-12-02 12:56:35
2228   3296      54            App\Models\Movie   4       2016-12-02 12:56:39   2016-12-02 12:56:39
2229   3296      40            App\Models\Movie   5       2016-12-02 12:56:43   2016-12-02 12:56:43
2230   3296      65            App\Models\Movie   6       2016-12-02 12:56:47   2016-12-02 12:56:47
```

In the example above if `lists.ordered = 0` it would grab row `2230` because it is the highest `order`. If `lists.ordered = 1` it would grab row `2226` because it is the lowest `order`. The highest works fine, but the lowest is grabbing `2224` which is the second lowest.

Comment: would you post some example table data from `cnt_lists` and `cnt` please?

Comment: @WEBjuju I have added the sample table data.

Comment: yes, that is sample table data.  please also provide some data from `cnt`.

Comment: @WEBjuju That data is from the `cnt_lists` table.

Comment: Is this homework/interview question to find the first/last without using `order by` or sub queries or the max concat trick? Because otherwise it is a very silly appoach to try to solve using joins.

Comment: @symcbean What method would you suggest I go with? I am ok taking a different approach,. I am just trying find the best approach to minimize my queries and prevent a N + 1 issue.

Comment: A good [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) would show the `lists` table because your query depends on `lists.ordered` or even better provide a http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: @ATLChris: you are adding extra constraints/requirements which were not stated in the problem, and it is far from clear what you are actually trying to achieve (e.g. your example data does not appear to show the data from one table when there are 2 involved, you have not provided the structure for either) hence we can't tell what the optimal solution is (but its not self-joins)

Comment: @symcbean http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/027b22/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to find 1st / last row ordered by the `order` column, but you did the ordering on the `id` column? In that case, try this:

SELECT lists.ordered,
       cnt1.*
FROM   cnt_lists AS cnt1
        LEFT JOIN lists
               ON cnt1.list_id = lists.id
        LEFT JOIN cnt_lists AS cnt2
              ON ( cnt1.list_id = cnt2.list_id
                   AND ( ( lists.ordered = 1
                           AND **cnt1.order** < **cnt2.order** )
                          OR ( lists.ordered = 0
                               AND **cnt1.order** > **cnt2.order** ) ) )
WHERE  cnt2.id IS NULL
       AND cnt1.list_id IN ( '3176', '3295', '3296' )
       AND cnt1.listable_type = 'App\Models\Movie';

Comment: I played a little with your fiddle, and it seems to work. 
[link] http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/027b22/10 [/link]

Comment: Great catch, thank you! I was pulling my hair out over this one.

Answer (score 2):

Don't try to do it in a single SQL.  Instead, write application code or a Stored Procedure to pick between 'first' and 'last'.

Even simpler than that is probably this:

```
SELECT ... FROM ...
    ORDER BY ordered ASC   -- ASC gives #1; DESC gives #6 in the example
    LIMIT 1;
```

If the output is more than one row, you may need [*Groupwise max*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/groupwise_max) problem.

OK, there is a messy way to do it in one statement:

```
( SELECT 0 AS which, ... ORDER BY ordered ASC  LIMIT 1 )
UNION ALL
( SELECT 1 AS which, ... ORDER BY ordered DESC LIMIT 1 )
HAVING which = (however you pick first vs last);
```

Comment: Wouldn't this be considered bad practice because of the n+1 issue? Meaning if I am looking this up for 150 different lists, it would require 150 individual queries. That is why I am trying to optimize it into one query.

Comment: That's where you need the Groupwise max link.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I have been fiddling around with the Groupwise max links recommendations but I am struggling how to accomplish both the max and min order. I have setup a fiddle to play around with this, but I can't see to get it working. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/027b22/2 I am ok to return the max and min row for each `list_id`, then I can determine which one to use at the php level. Thanks!

Comment: "struggling with both max and min" -- Enter my `UNION` suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the fiddle.  But...  What should the output be?  One row for each `list` entry?  A ordered list of 6 rows based on which `list` item is picked?